# apex:param not rendering

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to render the current week of the year on to a VF page with a custom controller I have added the value for the weekofyear into the controller and it appears to be ok. But when testing the value is not being outputted

This is the VF page

```
    <apex:page controller="AddingChildControllerv2" >
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >

 <apex:pageBlockSection >


   <apex:outputText value="Current Week:{0}">
    <apex:param value="{!weekOfYear}" />
   </apex:outputText>

</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
        <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!childList}" var="int">
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            <apex:commandLink value="Add" action="{!insertRow}"/>
            </apex:facet>



            <apex:column headerValue="Pay Run">
                <apex:inputField value="{!int.Pay_Run__c}"/>                                      
            </apex:column>


            <apex:column headerValue="Lead Generator">
                <apex:inputField value="{!int.Lead_Gen__c}"/>                                      
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Monday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Monday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Tuesday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Tuesday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Wednesday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Wednesday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Thursday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Thursday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Friday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Friday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Delete">
            <apex:commandLink style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;color:red;" value="X" action="{!delRow}">
                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:PageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insertChild}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And this is the controller

```
    public class AddingChildControllerv2 {
Id parentId;
public List<Time_Sheets__c> childList {get;set;}
public Integer rowNum{get;set;}

public Pay_Run__c Parent {get;set;}


 public Integer weekOfYear {get; set;}



public AddingChildControllerv2(){
    Id childId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('childId');
    childList = new List<Time_Sheets__c>();
    childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());
    ParentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ParentId');   


        Integer dayOfYear = Date.today().dayOfYear();
         Decimal weekOfYear = Math.mod(Integer.valueof(Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)), 52) + 1;

    }




public pagereference insertChild(){
    insert childList;

    Pagereference parentPage;
    if(!childList.isEmpty() && !string.isBlank(childList[0].Pay_Run__c))
        parentPage=new pagereference('/'+childList[0].Pay_Run__c);
    return parentPage;


}    

public void insertRow(){
    childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());


}

public void delRow(){
    rowNum = 
Integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));

childList.remove(rowNum);
}
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the output that I am getting as you can see the apex para is not rendering as expected

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized `weekOfYear` twice . `public Integer weekOfYear {get; set;}` and `Decimal weekOfYear = Math.mod(Integer.valueof(Math.ceil(dayOfYear / 7)), 52) + 1;`.
This is creating the issue. Modify your code by removing the decimal. It will work.

Comment: thank you very much